# Centring a <ul> or <div> at the bottom of a parent <div>

Tags: css

I'd like to end up with something similar to [this](http://tinypic.com/r/2lsgyvd/6)

The '22 November' element should be aligned at the bottom of the parent div and aligned in the centre. The remaining dates (21, 20, 19, 18) should then follow. (The central vertical line is just for illustration purposes).

Is this possible in css?

Edit: Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="motd">
        <ul>
            <li class="selected">22 November</li>
            <li>21</li>
            <li>20</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
 .container
    {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        overflow: hidden;
    }        

    #motd
    {
        width: 700px;
        height: 300px;     
        background-color: #efefef;       
        position: relative;
    }

    ul
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;          
    }

    li
    {
        float: left;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
        background-color: #cacaca; 
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    li.selected
    {
        background-color: #393939;   
    }
```

Comment: I've managed to get the ul at the bottom of the parent div (using position relative on the parent, position absolute on the child) but not centred as I'd like.

Answer (score 0):

use postion relative for the child and style the child

```
postion:relative;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
```

second option is give it a definite width and subtract by the parent div

parent div - child and then css  the child position absolute and left: the difference divided by two (basically you want even amount of pixels on each side

Comment: If I use position:relative on the child, how can I place it at the bottom of the parent div?

Comment: i mean you can just place by the top: attribute, but if you want to use bottom:0, you need absolute. what is the width of the child and what is the width of the parent

Comment: I've added my code so far in the original question. My parent div is a fixed width of 700px. The width of my child ul or div is going to be unknown (it's dynamic based upon the date etc).

Answer (score 0):

You musn't set a `left` position. Only position the element absolutely to the bottom (as you have done) and then center it by setting the left and right margins to `auto`.

```
ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can also set the width for the list to 100% and center the child `li`'s in the list.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the <ul> is still left aligned. I've created a JSFiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Gwcbd/1/

Comment: @chut319 Yep, as far as I can see from the fiddle, you need to set the width of the list to 100% and center the list item within. The question is how to center list items in a list. Try to search for that.

Comment: center list items? give them a class position relative and margin auto, its simple.. VERY IMPORTANT to give them a width because by default they will be the width of the ul so it wont get centered because its at 100% width.

Comment: @Dnaso That's complete nonsense. It's not about centering a list inside a wrapper, but centering a row of say five list items next to each other inside their parent list element. Normally you also didn't want to set a width to the list items, as they should shrink and expand with the text content.

Comment: no you give padding to each side and center the text padding-left:5px padding-right:5px now it will look like there is an even amount of space inbetween each one. and your question is very vague and confusing, you should have said that from start.